# ClassCastException - related to JSON parsing, came out of nowhere

Tags: android, classcastexception

My app was seemingly running fine for a while now, when all of a sudden I started getting a ClassCastException when running a portion of the app that runs a query via REST API.  I have no idea where it came from or why it cropped up now, as it was working one instant, and then when I re-ran it to test a different search query, it ran into the error.  The error is pointing to the following methods, specifically the first line within the `try` block - `JSONObject resultsWrapper = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();` :

```
    private static void getResultsFromJson(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject resultsWrapper = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue(); 
        JSONArray  results        = resultsWrapper.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = result.getString("from_user"); 
            String geo = result.getString("text");  

            VenueList.addVenue(name, geo);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON.", e);
    }
}
```

Full disclosure: `VenueList` is a class built to store data returned from the results and is accessible globally.  I can post code if it is deemed necessary.

The error also points to the following method, in the same Fragment as the one above, specifically where `getResultsFromJson(restResult)` is called:

```
public void onRESTResult(int code, String restResult) { 
    if (code == 200 && restResult != null) {

        getResultsFromJson(restResult);
        mResults = VenueList.venueNames;
        setResults();           
    }
    else {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to load Twitter data. Check your internet settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the above two methods are in a Fragment that extends the following Fragment, where the error points specifically to ` onRESTResult(resultCode, resultData.getString(RESTService.REST_RESULT));':

```
public abstract class RESTResponderFragment extends Fragment {

private ResultReceiver mReceiver;

public RESTResponderFragment() {
    mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultData != null && resultData.containsKey(RESTService.REST_RESULT)) {
                onRESTResult(resultCode, resultData.getString(RESTService.REST_RESULT));
            }
            else {
                onRESTResult(resultCode, null);
            }
        }

    };
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
}

public ResultReceiver getResultReceiver() {
    return mReceiver;
}

abstract public void onRESTResult(int code, String result);
}
```

Here is the full error log:

```
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at com.example.blobtag2.fragment.FactualResponderFragment.getResultsFromJson(FactualResponderFragment.java:152)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at com.example.blobtag2.fragment.FactualResponderFragment.onRESTResult(FactualResponderFragment.java:106)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at com.example.blobtag2.fragment.RESTResponderFragment$1.onReceiveResult(RESTResponderFragment.java:23)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable.run(ResultReceiver.java:43)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4358)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-16 22:20:16.270: E/AndroidRuntime(17906):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This came about at the same time that I got an error about the project being unable to build - "Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project".

Let me know if there's any other code that might be useful.  Really confused as this came completely out of nowhere, would love any insight anyone might have into how to fix this and/or why it came about.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems like there's something unexpected in your JSON response. The code is expecting an object and `nextValue` is returning a `String`. Best thing to do is to look at the JSON source that you're trying to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

nextValue returns  JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double or NULL.

So its not always a JSONObject.  If its one of the other types, that's an illegal cast.

My normal way to deal with JSON was always to pass the string into a JSONObject directly, and then parse the JSONObject.  But if you're expecting long strings, that would be inefficient.  If you want to use a tokenizer, you're going to need to check datatype via instanceof.

Comment: But why was this working fine before?  I changed nothing about what I am calling and the results are the same.  Also, added edit related to build error upon start-up of eclipse.. not sure if related.

Comment: My guess is different data (perhaps with a format error) from the server.  Have you checked what the json string is when it crashes?